# SBT how to run InputTask

Tags: scala, sbt

I am creating some custom tasks in my SBT project and need to call other tasks for that.

How can i call inputTasks from inside my tasks and support them some input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can factor your own tasks around this I'm assuming you're trying to use the `run` task. It took a bit of digging, but I've finally made it work; in a nutshell, this is what you do (assuming your task is named `deployTask`, tweak to match your needs):

```
deployTask <<= ( fullClasspath in Compile, runner ) map { ( classpath, runner ) =>
        val logger = ConsoleLogger()    // Not sure this is optimal
        Run.executeTrapExit( {
            Run.run( "com.sample.MainClass", 
                     classpath map { _.data }, 
                     Seq( "option1", "option2", "..." ),  // <-- Options go here
                     logger )( runner )
        }, logger )
    }
```

This doesn't invoke the `InputTask` directly (I haven't found a way to do that yet), but it at least lets you run arbitrary Java code.

Comment: This was a great help. I've been searching for a few hours now, trying to find out how to run an `InputTask` directly. You mentioned that you hadn't found out how *yet*... several months ago - any chance that you've figured it out since then?

Comment: Sorry, no. To be honest we've switched to Maven - it's not as elegant but is far easier to get the team up and running with.