# How to pass arguments to InputTask without entering sbt interactive mode?

Tags: sbt

With the following sample SBT build file, I can pass arguments to my InputTask from within the SBT Interactive Mode but not from without. Is there a way?

Sample build.sbt:

```
import complete.DefaultParsers._

lazy val sampleDoSomething = inputKey[Unit]("Will print arguments.")

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val taskInputTaskProject = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    sampleDoSomething := {
      println("Arguments: ")
      val args = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      args foreach println
    }
  )
```

Successfully invoking task from within SBT Interactive mode:

```
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to taskInputTaskProject (in build file:/study/sbt/input-tasks/)
> sampleDoSomething a b c
Arguments: 
a
b
c
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 22, 2016 1:06:58 PM
```

Successfully Invoking task from command line without arguments:

```
$ sbt sampleDoSomething
[info] Set current project to taskInputTaskProject (in build file:/study/sbt/input-tasks/)
Arguments: 
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 22, 2016 1:06:18 PM
```

Failure to invoke task from command line with arguments:

```
$ sbt sampleDoSomething a b c
[info] Set current project to taskInputTaskProject (in build file:/study/sbt/input-tasks/)
Arguments: 
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 22, 2016 1:06:44 PM
[error] Not a valid command: a
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Not a valid project ID: a
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: a
[error] a
[error]  ^
```

Comment: Clearly related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352400/sbt-how-to-run-inputtask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt "sampleDoSomething a b c"`

See doc: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode

Cheers

Comment: Ah, very good. 

I had previously tried `sbt sampleDoSomething "a b c"` but didn't think to also include the task in the quotes.